# Calculation of a formula with Python's math library

Tags: python, math

[image]
According to the **picture** that contains the formula, I wrote the following code
**But the numbers I give in the input are wrong**

```
import math as m
x = int(input())
r=m.ceil(m.pow(x,(5/3))+m.tan(x))
y = m.floor(m.pow(m.pi, 2+m.atan(m.pow(m.sin(m.radians(x)), 2))))
print(m.gcd(r,y))
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask] and https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/, and try to consider the code closely. Hint: See where it says `m.sin(m.radians(x))`? What is the purpose of the `m.radians` part? Now, see where it says `m.tan(x)`. Does something appear to be missing?

Comment: Is x given in radians or degrees? Because if it's in degrees then @cardstdani is right, if it's given in radians you should remove the `m.radians()`from y

Answer (score 3):

You need to convert to radians when using `math.tan()`, as well as the rest of the trigonometric functions:

```
import math as m
x = int(input())
r=m.ceil(m.pow(x,(5/3))+m.tan(m.radians(x)))
y = m.floor(m.pow(m.pi, 2+m.atan(m.pow(m.sin(m.radians(x)), 2))))
print(m.gcd(r,y))
```

Also, if the input is in radians, you must remove `m.radians()` then